# Сохранение статистики просмотров (Структура mysql таблицы)

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

Есть магазины, у них есть товары. Помогите советом, как бы сохранять в БД просмотры товаров. На графике выводятся просмотры за месяца и за отдельные дни.

Первое, что приходит в голову:
Две таблицы в одной просмотры за дни, в другой соответственно за месяца.
Но данный вариант кажется слишком громоздким и некрасивым

Comment: Товары можно смотреть поштучно, а можно группой на странице, товары могут располагаться на отдельной на странице (т.е. одна страница - один товар), а могут запрашиваться скопом и отображаться на одной странице (по типу медиа-галереи) и т.д. Необходимо привести как ваши товары отображаются, в какой момент необходимо вести статистику и какая именно статистика вас интересует.

Comment: Как отображаются, это не важно. Каждый день крон получает просмотры. Вычитая кол-во просмотров за предыдущий день мы можем узнать сколько просмотров за сегодняшний день. Вопрос состоит как удобнее и компактнее хранить эти данные в БД

Comment: Т.е. у вас уже есть сохранение статистики, но вы думаете как можно улучшить ваше решение? В вопросе этого не видно

Comment: Извините, при данном уточнении мой ответ не содержит для вас информации.

Comment: Возможно вам стоит посмотреть как храниться информация о просмотрах в CMS Magento. Там функционал, нужный вам представлен в лучшем виде.

Comment: @BOPOH на данный момент есть суммарное кол-во просмотров каждого товара. Теперь нужно сделать функционал, который покажет сколько просмотров было за определённый день или месяц

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходный вопрос не изобилует конкретикой, поэтому приведу решение для общего случая учета статистики чего-либо. Обычно задача решается в несколько этапов.

1. Накопление статистики по просмотрам. Каждый просмотр сохраняется в базу данных отдельной записью. Структура БД может содержать следующие поля:

   - `created`: временная метка UNIX соответствующая моменту просмотра
   - `product_id`: ID просмотренного товара (страницы, новости, ...)
   - дополнительные поля, для построения расширенной статистики (`user_id`, `ip`, `country`, ...).
2. Выбирается минимальный промежуток времени (например один день). Регулярно (например, раз в день), производится суммирование статистики по этим промежуткам. Результаты суммирования заносятся в другую базу, данные из которой и выводятся в виде графиков и таблиц. Структура этой таблицы может иметь следующий вид:

   - `date`: дата, для которой подсчитаны просмотры
   - `views_count`: количество просмотров
   - дополнительные поля (например, среднее количество просомотров одним пользователем).
3. Строятся графики, по интересующим периодам. Поскольку, при суммировании в п.2 был выбран *минимальный дискретный промежуток времени*, постольку любые временные интервалы могут быть построены из нескольких минимальных простыми аггрегирующими SQL запросами.

Если нет необходимости строить сложную расширенную статистику, то пункт 1 можно пропустить и сохранять данные сразу в формате из пункта 2.

Comment: Спасибо, понял что лучший вариант вышеописаный. Сегодня обойдёмся без "велосипедов")

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос стоит именно в выводе статистических данных, лучше пользоваться каким-либо счетчиком, например я пользуюсь [Яндекс.Метрикой](https://metrika.yandex.ru/) для получения статистики. Также там можно настроить цели для визитов и пользователей.

Метрикой от Яндекса список не ограничивается. Есть Google Analitycs и другие системы. Даже присутствуют OpenSource решения, [Piwik](http://piwik.org/).

Всё зависит от требований. Уточните их и сообщество поможет в выборе реализации.

**UPD:**

Предлагаю автору ознакомиться со страницами помощи Яндекс.Метрики:

1. Цели — [основные возможности и назначение](https://yandex.ru/support/metrika/reports/add-goals.xml)
2. Карта ссылок — [как выглядит и зачем это нужно](https://yandex.ru/support/metrika/behavior/link-map.xml)
3. Функции для ИМ — [пример](https://yandex.ru/support/metrika/reports/e-commerce.xml)

Думаю вышепредложенные ссылки внесут ясность, как именно можно использовать статистику, собранную метрикой, а так же подскажут ответ на комментарий о невозможности использования для подсчета информации по посещаемым страницам.

Comment: Нужно предоставить пользователю красивые графики просмотров его продукции за день/месяц. А насколько я понимаю разнообразные Яндекс.Метрики предоставляют статистику просмотров/переходов конкретно на сайт. Без привязки к конкретным страницам

Comment: Думаю, автор, вы в корне не правы. Я рекомендую ознакомиться с разделом "Помощь" у "разнообразных Яндекс.Метрик", перед утверждением что такого функционала нет.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, но всё же. Сайт по идее напоминает доску обьявлений. Если добавиться новая единица товара, то нужно будет вручную создавать счётчик для данного товара, что не очень подходит.

Comment: Счетчик для этого товара не нужно создавать, при посещении, эта страница автоматически появится в метрике, если на нее будет заходить пользователь. Автор, прочитайте "помощь" по ссылке, вы не верно понимаете суть счетчиков. ИМХО - пытаетесь изобрести велосипед.